# How can I setup a simple email subscription mailing list in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I setup a simple email subscription mailing list feature for a rails 4 app which is basically just a personal "homepage" for a singer?

Should I be using Action Mailer, integrating something like Mail Chimp, set up an Email model, something completely different or a combo?

The test I'm starting with is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'join mailing list' do

  scenario 'can join mailing list' do
    visit '/'
    fill_in 'Email address', with: 'email@gmail.com'
    click_button 'Join mailing list'
    expect(page).to have_content('Thanks for joining!')
  end

end
```

Comment: You're asking someone else to write your entire app, and all you have is an acceptance test. What code have you tried up to this point? You need to put effort into trying to build something first, then ask for help when you run into specific problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I just want an indication of which path I should start heading down - happy to do the coding myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail Chimp will give you a wild range of features you might not need at this point. It's also a paid product.

If you want to give this a go you would probably need a few more tables in your database.

First off you need to create a record of all users that are signed up. One of the things you need to keep track of is the option to opt-out. So at minimum you need an email-address and an opted-out boolean in this table.

Now you can either create a a single page where your client can copy and paste all the email addresses that are not opted out to a bcc field in his own email client or you can create an other page where you give him a WYSIWYG editor and when he presses send you use ActionMailer to send the email to all users in the database.

If you want to go an extra step you could keep track of all sent emails and their content and perhaps add macro's your client can use.

This should be enough inspiration to get you started... Hopefully :)

Comment: Got it - thanks. So Action Mailer can't capture and manage the subscribers' emails and I have to create the subscribers table which can then be passed to Action Mailer.

Comment: You got it, that's exactly what is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the general flow of your app, since that is the first thing that user experiences you should start with that, but do make sure that you include actionmailer and check its deliveries, make sure the emails sent to includes the receivers user_email.